# printf NULL without quotes or not NULL, with quotes for sql statement

Tags: c, printf

I'm writing a program to print out many thousands of lines of (MySQL) SQL instructions to be sent to a database server in asynchronous time.
Each set of SQL instructions will be saved to a file via a *nix pipe redirection.

The problem I'm facing is about `NULL` values for `char *` fields.
If there's a

```
printf ( "\"%s\" ", foo_field);
```

and foo_field might be or might not be `NULL`.

MySQL needs to receive a plain `NULL`, not a `"NULL"`, so I must get rid of double quotes just when there's a `NULL` value.  When the value is not `NULL`, it must be enclosed in double quotes.

For the case I've shown I could place a `if   then` so that the parameter would be `%s` if `NULL` or `\"%s\"` if not `NULL`.

But if we consider a SQL line with twenty fields, it's not so great to do it this way.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `if(foo_field)printf(( "\"%s\" ", foo_field);else printf("NULL ");`

Comment: Why do you think if-else is not a good option?

Comment: Do you print only text strings or do you also print numbers?

Comment: `printf(foo_field ? "\"%s\" " : "%s ", foo_field);`

Comment: @Alexey: This is for text strings and numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, your problem is that it's ugly to if-then-else multiple times?

How about a function?

```
void print_field (const char *field) {
  if (field)
    printf ("\"%s\" ", field);
  else
    printf ("NULL ");
}
```

Then in your real code:

```
print_field (foo_field);
print_field (bar_field);
......
```

If you make sure the function is in the same file (declared with `static`) then the compiler will probably inline it, if it judges that to be more efficient.

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that there may need to be more complex printf statements like `printf("%d %s %s %f %d %s", ...);`.

Comment: That's the case Alexey, about twenty fields in some sql commands.

Comment: If he wants to have a conditional for every argument then I don't see another way. If he has to do this 200 times, each with 20 arguments, then inventing his own printf equivalent might be a plan, but let's start simple.

Answer (score 1):

Ahem. *cough*...

Be aware that the behaviour of `printf( "%s" )` for NULL pointers is **undefined**.

Not in the sense of whether there will be quotation marks around any `NULL` or `null` or `nil` or empty string, but in the sense that your application might simply crash.

And that is why the C/C++ credo is to *not* add safety nets to standard functions. Not only does the library do an `if` - `else` on your pointer to save you from crashing. No, if you want to play it safe, you *have* to add *another* `if` - `else` so as to not rely on the implementation...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that foo_field is a char array at least longer by 2 chars than your field.

```
void add_quotes_unless_NULL(char* str)
{
    if (strncmp("NULL", str, 5) != 0)
    {
        char prev = str[0];
        str[0] = '\"';
        int i;
        for (i = 1; prev; ++i)
        {
            char curr = str[i];
            str[i] = prev;
            prev = curr;
        }
        str[i] = '\"';
        str[i+1] = '\n';
    }
}
```

Now use it this way:

```
add_quotes_unless_NULL(foo_field);
printf ( "%s ", foo_field);
```